# Великое Лайнландское переселение

Tags: c++

Код выдает ошибку на каком-то тесте
Знаю, что задача с Сириуса, но спешу вас предупредить, я в нем не участвую, поэтому я не стану тем нехорошим человеком,который займет ваше место на очном туре)
Задача:
Великое Лайнландское переселение
Лайнландия представляет собой одномерный мир, являющийся прямой, на котором распологаются N городов, последовательно пронумерованных от 0 до N− 1. Направление в сторону от первого города к нулевому названо западным, а в обратную — восточным.

Когда в Лайнландии неожиданно начался кризис, все жители одномерного мира стали испытывать глубокое смятение. По всей Лайнландии стали ходить слухи, что на востоке живётся лучше, чем на западе.

Так и началось Великое Лайнландское переселение. Обитатели мира целыми городами отправились на восток, покинув родные улицы, и двигались до тех пор, пока не приходили в город, в котором средняя цена проживания была меньше, чем в родном.

Входные данные

В первой строке дано одно число N (2 ≤N≤ 105) — количество городов в Лайнландии. Во второй строке даны N чисел ai (0 ≤ai≤ 109) — средняя цена проживания в городах с нулевого по (N− 1)-й соответственно.

Выходные данные

Для каждого города в порядке с нулевого по (N− 1)-й выведите номер города, в который переселятся его изначальные жители. Если жители города не остановятся в каком-либо другом городе, отправившись в Восточное Бесконечное Ничто, выведите −1.

Примеры
Ввод
10
1 2 3 2 1 4 2 5 3 1

Вывод
-1 4 3 4 -1 6 9 8 9 -1

Сам код:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

#define int long long

using namespace std;

signed main() 
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n), ans(n, -1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> a[i];
        
    vector<int> st;
    st.push_back(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        while (a[st.back()] > a[i])
        {
            ans[st.back()] = i;
            st.pop_back();
        }
        st.push_back(i);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << ans[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не учитываете вариант, когда нужно вывести -1. Вы из пустого стека делаете  `pop()`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/497884)

Comment: @Sergei Buvaka Почему это не является? Вполне себе мощная подсказка.

Comment: @MBo, это подсказка на грубую ошибку, но вся логика выполнения не верна

Comment: Это подсказка, а не ответ на вопрос. Для этого есть комментарии

Comment: @LIshy2,если не сложно,не могли бы вы дать какой-нибудь тест-пример, чтобы повторить ту ошибку

Comment: @Syr3333 если хотите получить пример - пишите стресс. Хорошая привычка